# combobox loses selected value while scrolling listview

Tags: c#, listview, windows-8, winrt-xaml

I am working on a win 8 app. I have a listview with combobox inside datatemlate. Now problem occurs when I scroll listview, combobox loses selectedvalue infact while scrolling listview combobox selectedValueChanged event fires.

```
<ListView x:Name="lstQuestion" Margin="0 10 0 0" SelectionMode="None"                         
    ItemsSource="{Binding QuestionsViewModel.AuditQuestionList}" IsItemClickEnabled="True" >
    <ListView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="10 0 0 0">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding QuestionText}" Padding="14,10,10,10" FontSize="14" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">

                    <Rectangle ToolTipService.ToolTip="{Binding QuestionText}" x:Name="rectAnswerColor"  Fill="{Binding ProgressColor, Converter={StaticResource HexToSolidColorConverter}}" Width="5" Height="40"/>
                    <ComboBox x:Name="cmbanswer" Margin="10 0 0 0"   Height="40" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Width="200" ItemsSource="{Binding PossibleAnswerList}" Visibility="{Binding QuestionType, Converter={StaticResource IntToVisibility1}}" SelectionChanged="cmbanswer_SelectionChanged_1" />

                    <TextBox x:Name="txtAnswer" Margin="10 0 0 0" Height="40" Width="200" Visibility="{Binding QuestionType, Converter={StaticResource IntToVisibility2}}" LostFocus="txtAnswer_LostFocus_1"/>

                    <Image x:Name="imgcamera" Source="/Assets/camera.png" Height="35" Width="30" Margin="15 0 0 0" Tapped="imgcamera_Tapped_1"/>

                    <Border x:Name="brdBackground" Margin="-8 -20 0 0" Background="Red" CornerRadius="10" Height="22" Width="22" >
                        <TextBlock x:Name="tblImageCount" Text="+"  Foreground="White" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="12"/>
                    </Border>

                    <Image x:Name="imgnote" Source="/Assets/notepad.png" Height="30" Width="30" Margin="15 0 0 0" Tapped="imgnote_Tapped"/>
                </StackPanel>
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Is there any problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try to disable the scrolling property of ListView when ComboBox.IsDropDownOpen == true

Comment: My problem is that after selecting value in combobox, when i scroll down listview and then up again, combox loses value. I just find out out that when I am scrolling listview, get method of binding property of combobox itemsource called.

Comment: If 'SelectionChanged' event of combobox fires while scrolling ListView, then it means the combo box has the focus still. If you are able to set focus to ListView or to some other control, then add this event to your combobox, `ComboBox.DropDownClosed += your event`. In the event set focus to some other control, i.e, remove the focus focus from combo box.

Answer (score 0):

I added a scrollviewer for listview and it works. Something happening with listview when scrolling, Its redrawing items which are not visible or something. Anyways thanks for replying.